# UIView in nib not connecting to IBOutlets

Tags: ios, xcode

I am adding on screen a UIView in this way:

```
ViewController2 *detailViewController = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MJDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentPopupViewController:detailViewController animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
```

since MJDetailViewController is a nib and holds a UIView, I have created a custom class of UIView and selected it as class for the view in the inspector. When the window is loaded, the UIButtons do actions in the class that has been created, but the IBOutlets don't work. Even if I decided to add a UIButton programmably, it doesn't appear on screen. Why is this?

I thought of changing the UIView to a UIViewController, but it won't work because you can't present it with an animation.

Comment: Please provide some code in DetailViewController.Or screen shot of xib how you have set the UIView.Also change the color of DetailViewController.Or so that you can sure that the correct controller is getting loaded(only for testing purpose).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you haven't set up the nib objects correctly.

In addition to setting the class of your UIView subclass you need to configure the 'File's Owner' and connect the views to it. You do this by selecting the file owner and setting its' class (this is done the same as setting the view's class). In your case the class of the file owner should be `ViewController2`.

Hopefully this screenshot explains this better:
[image: Setting up a view controllers nib]

Also you can simplify things a bit by using `UIViewController` nib naming conventions. If you give your nib the same file name as the view controller then you can specify `nil` as the `nibName:`. For example, if you name your nib `ViewController2.xib` then you can do this:

`ViewController2 *detailViewController = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

This approach is preferable as it means that the nib filename becomes an implementation details which calling code does not need to know about.

Comment: I have set the files owner to the view subclass and connected but the app crashes. If I set to ViewController2 I can't do anything because it is empty. all the code is in the UIView subclass

Comment: Have you added an `IBOutlet` to `ViewController2` so that you can connect your view? What information is logged when the app crashes?